# Suppose that $T$ is the smallest positive integer satisfying $m^{T}\equiv \pmod {pq}$. Prove that $T\mid(p-1)(q-1)$.

Tags: proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes and that $m$ is an integer satisfying $\gcd(m, pq) = 1$.  Suppose that $T$ is the smallest positive integer satisfying $m^{T}\equiv \pmod {pq}$.  Prove that $T\mid(p-1)(q-1)$.

I know that this is RSA encryption, but how do I go about proving this?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually $T$ needs to divide $$[p-1,q-1]$$

Comment: As lab mentions, there is a stronger result that holds which is $T\mid\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$; the proof is similar using Carmichael's lambda function instead of Euler's totient function. $$T\mid\lambda(pq)=\operatorname{lcm}(\lambda(p),\lambda(q))=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$$

The conclusion desired in the question is a corollary of the above result since $\lambda(n)\mid\varphi(n)$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Answer (score 1):

By the Euler's theorem, if $\gcd(x,n)=1$, then 
$$
x^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\ (\text{mod}\,n) 
$$ 
Therefore, $\text{ord}_n(x)\mid \varphi(n)$. In particular, for $n=pq$, $x=m$ and $T=\text{ord}_n(m)$ we obtain
$$
T\mid \varphi(pq)=(p-1)(q-1)
$$
as required.

Comment: May I ask what ord() is referring to? I haven't seen that notation before.

Comment: $\text{ord}_n(x)$ is the order of $x$ modulo $n$, that is, $\text{ord}_n(x)$ is the smallest positive integer $t$ such that $x^t\equiv 1$ modulo $n$.

Comment: I see, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The proof is simple:

We have $\gcd(m, pq) = 1$, then **Euler Theoreme** say:

$$m^{(p-1)(q-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$$

You Defined $T$ as the smallest number verify : $m^{T} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$ with $T\neq 0$

Then using euclidian division of $(p-1)(q-1)$ by $T$ :

$$(p-1)(q-1) = T n + r , \quad 0 \leq r < T$$

Then:

$$m^{r} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$$

Then $r=0$ ($T$ is the smallest number verify : $m^{T} \equiv 1 \pmod{pq}$ with $T\neq 0$)

Then $T$ devide $(p-1)(q-1)$